# ggmap errors when using aesthetics beyond x/y

Tags: r, ggmap

I've been using ggmap for several years now. A few weeks ago I started getting weird error messages when plotting with it; not sure if I did anything to cause it. It seems that the problems start when I try to use more than the coords - any other aesthetic use (colour / fill / etc) results in an error, as does facetting.

To address this, I installed R 3.5.1 and re-installed the ggmap package to make sure I'm using the most up-to-date stuff. I'm assuming the issue is with me and not the package, since I didn't see anything similar when googling.

toy data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

df <- data.frame(Group = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 20, replace = TRUE), 
  x = rnorm(20, -116.1, 0.001), y = rnorm(20, 48.5, 0.001))

prep <- get_googlemap(center = c(-116.1, 48.5),
  zoom = 15, maptype = 'satellite', scale = 2)
```

runs ok, but gives a warning that "panel.margin is deprecated"

```
map <- ggmap(prep, size = c(100, 200), 
   extent='device', darken = 0,
   legend = "bottom", data = df)
```

gives a long output of theme elements that are missing, but plots the output

```
map + 
   geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y), colour = "white") +
   facet_wrap(~ Group)
```

gives a long output of theme elements that are missing, as well as an error `Error in unit(rep(just$hjust, n), "npc") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0`

```
map + 
   geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y), colour = "white") +
   facet_wrap(~ Group)
```

also long list of missing theme elements, as well as a different error: `Error in UseMethod("element_grob") : no applicable method for 'element_grob' applied to an object of class "NULL"`

```
map + 
   geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = Group))
```

session info:
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
ggmap version: 2.6.1

Comment: I'm on a mac with R 3.5.1, `ggplot2` 3.0.0, and `ggmap` 2.7.900 (github version), and run this with no problems or the warnings you posted. Try upgrading `ggmap` and/or restarting your session. There are also a few issues on the [`ggmap` github](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues) on interactions between the 2 packages.

Comment: Oh, the github version of ggmap worked, thank you! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: If it's just a versioning issue, I don't think it would be a reproducible answer. Keeping packages updated isn't a solution to this specific problem so much as a good all around practice

Comment: Is the github version considered "the updated one"? I was always under the impression that the CRAN versions are the officially released ones? Just for my own knowledge. As I mentioned in the post, I had the latest CRAN version installed, but the github one solved my issue.

Comment: Oh you're right, what you've got is the latest CRAN release, although there hasn't been a CRAN release of `ggmap` in 2.5 years. What version of `ggplot2` were you using? 3.0.0 was a pretty big update, so I'm still guessing it's incompatibility between the versions of the two packages

Comment: ggplot2 was 3.0.0. Yay, version incompatibility and github versions to solve issues :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in comments. Solution was:

```
devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap", ref = "tidyup")
```